# Can a bivariate polynomial with only algebraic coefficients have monic polynomial factors with non-algebraic coefficients?

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Can a bivariate polynomial with only algebraic coefficients have monic polynomial factors with non-algebraic coefficients?

Are there literature references with lists of bivariate polynomials that are irreducible over the algebraic numbers?

I already know that a bivariate polynomial can have solutions $(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: Consider $\,f = gh = \pi g\,(\pi^{-1} h).\ $ If you wish to exclude such then you need to be more precise.

Answer (score -1):

The quick answer is no:

Anytime you factor a polynomial of one or several variables $f \in K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$
you can rescale the factors so that the coefficient of each factor is algebraic over the 
field generated by the coefficients of $f$.  The reason is that each polynomial can be factored in (essentially) finitely many ways into two factors.